# Spring reloadable Properties to be accessed all at once

Tags: spring, localization

I can't figure out a way of getting ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadable abilities and having access to Properties / all messages at once by locale. ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource API doesn't provide access to anything but individual messages by code and lang... ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource can't be even extended to access Properties because of member visibility.

Any idea how to have reloadable properties and access them all at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just coded this, hope it works but you will need to optimize stuff, I suppose the method can be static or if you need it to become a bean then obtain basename and locale from the base class.

```
package mx.gob.jgtjo.apps.schedule.web.utils;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;

public class CustomMessageResolver extends
          ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

     public CustomMessageResolver() {

     }

     public Map<Object, Object> loadAllMessagesByLocale(String basename,
               Locale locale) {

          List<String> fileNames = super
                    .calculateAllFilenames(basename, locale);

          Map<Object, Object> messagesByLocale = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

          for (String fileName : fileNames) {

               PropertiesHolder holder = super.getProperties(fileName);

               for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : holder.getProperties()
                         .entrySet()) {

                    messagesByLocale.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
               }

          }

          return messagesByLocale;

     }
}
```

UPDATE: I found a better way to get all properties from the basenames specified:

```
public class CustomMessageResolver extends
          ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

     public CustomMessageResolver() {

     }

     public Map<Object, Object> loadAllMessagesByLocale(String basename,
               Locale locale) {

          Map<Object, Object> messagesByLocale = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

          PropertiesHolder holder = super.getMergedProperties(locale);

          for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : holder.getProperties().entrySet()) {

               messagesByLocale.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
          }

          return messagesByLocale;

     }
}
```

This will take the basenames from the base class.